# Combinatorics calc

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to make an application that's based on bets system.
Until now i was able to calc the number of combination of the inserted events, in particular, i've used this formula:

$$c=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Don't panic, this formula is very simple to use, now I explain.
$n$ = events 
$k$ = combinations 
The exclamation point means you have to apply the rule of the factorial.

Now I make a numerical example. Suppose we have $5$ events and make a triple combinations (3), then monetize variables in this way: $n = 5, k = 3$. The result will be:

$$c = \frac{5\times4\times3\times2}{3\times2\times(5-3)!}$$
$$c = \frac{120}{6\times2}$$
$$c = 10$$

Ok, "c" therefore describes the total combinations for the data previously entered.
The algorithm of the function described above have already made and is functioning.
Now that I have explained how the system works, I present my problem.
First, remember that c = 10 (10 combinations generated by triple), then we apply this number of events taken at random in each game.
We have selected the following events:

http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2d3c/lcyv3lngn2lvlhzzg.jpg

how see in the image, the events selected is "5", so the generated combination are:

http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/67ec/xx7tv9w8l38voqfzg.jpg

Here is my problem.
As you can see every event will repeat a minimum of "6" Sometimes, I have not been able to figure out which distribution formula is applied by the system and would like your help.
Shown in the picture you see that were created 10 lines, each line has three combinations. I would just like to understand why each event appears 6 times, which formula is applied?
Thank You.

Comment: People on this site generally know what combinations and factorials are and how they are computed, so I think most of the intro is unnecessary. Writing for the right audience and all that.

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended anyone linger too.
But I want to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @epimorphic I think, that to explain a bit more about the problem is better then doing it the other way round. I would even say, that this is a reason to upvote the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be any $5$-element set. As you've shown, the number of $3$-element subsets of $A$ is $$\binom{5}{3}=10$$

If $x \in A$, how many of these $3$ element subsets contain $x$? Well, we can count the number that *do not* contain $x$, and then subtract that from $10$.

But the number of three-element subsets of $A$ that don't contain $x$ is just the number of three-element subsets of $A -\{x\}$, which is the number of three-element subsets of a four-element set, which is

$$\binom{4}{3}=4$$

Therefore, the number of three-element subsets of $A$ that contain $x$ is

$$\binom{5}{3}-\binom{4}{3}=10-4=\boxed{6}$$

This is why each of what you call "events" shows up $6$ times in the list of sets of $3$ "events." Not only will each "event" repeat a minimum of six (as you said), it will repeat *exactly* six times in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still can't understand how he obtained 4, used a generic formula?

Comment: The number of ways you can have a $3$-element subset of a $5$-element set but without one of the elements, is simply the number of $3$-element subsets of a $4$-element set. Just like your initial calculation was $\binom{5}{3}$, this one is $\binom{4}{3}$. This means the number of ways that *do* include a specific element is $$\binom{5}{3}-\binom{4}{3} = 10-4 = 6$$

Comment: I'm using [this notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula) for binomial coefficients.